# Spring / Gradle project using Hibernate issuing a warning (error to my partner) about not being able to connect to database

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

I am working on a Spring/Gradle project using IntelliJ and I want to use Hibernate to connect with the database. I implemented :

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
```

in my gradle build file.
I have also created a HibernateConfig class which takes `dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword` from my application properties file. When I run the project I get the following warning:

```
2020-09-11 18:37:23.593  WARN 14996 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/data_beer_tag
```

When my partner pulled it from GitLab, he received not a warning but an error? Any Idea what I could be doing wrong? As far as I know I am not supposed to download the drivers separately and gradle is taking care of all dependancies.

Comment: @aburaks thanks, I will try this appoach too since it seems more correct, but all that is still new to me so I need to figure out how to do some of the stuff manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the mariadb part of the url with mysql. It is not as the server generated it but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string shows that you are using MariaDB, Adding MariaDB driver instead of MySQL driver dependency may solve your problem.

```
implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.6.2'
```